# disprove that f is continuous with use of its components

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. I need to prove/disprove the claim which says:

$f$ is continuous $\iff$ $f(x,\cdot), f(\cdot, y)\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous for every $y,x$ respectively.

I am pretty sure that this claim isn't true, so I'm going with disprove here.

My counter example was the function $f(x,y) = \cfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ which is continuous for $x$ alone and for $y$ alone, but $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist. Which means $f$ isn't continuous.

However, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right.

Comment: You're in the right direction, but you need to complete f by defining f(0)=0.  Moreover, adding a simple substitution y=mx is better.

Answer (score 0):

Specific example for disproof:  Let $x=y$, then $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$ and $y$.  Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0}=\frac{1}{2}$ in this direction, which differs from letting them $\to 0$ separately, where the limit is $0$.